# Get the time when the page loads angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to get and assign to a variable the time my app runs on the browser. I'm using angular js.All I have in my mind now is just this

```
    time is:
        </div>  
        <div class="item_contentbox">
          <span my-current-time='h:m'>
          </span>
```

Can someone please give me a sample on how can I get the time my app loads on the browser? Help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use the `.run()` block on your application module. Get the time using plain JavaScript, or using a library like momentjs. Set that into a `$rootScope.currentTime` variable, and bind your span to that variable `<span ng-bind="currentTime">`. This assumes are you are using AngularJS 1.x and not 2.0.

I haven't tested this, but it should be something like

```
angular.module('yourAppName', [injected dependencies here...])
  .config(yourConfigFunctionHere)
  .run(function($rootScope) {
     var d = new Date();
     $rootScope.currentTime = d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds();
   });
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm new in angularjs and can't understand it clearly at one shot can you give me a sample if it's not too much?

Comment: Take a look now. Hopefully that sends you in the right direction.

Comment: im sorry but I still don't get the idea can you look at my plunker?It only shows the current time but not the time the program runs. Can you help me with this please? http://plnkr.co/edit/4XRjszIATgvUVrofgRFI?p=preview

Comment: In your Plunker, I can see that you have a directive called myCurrentTime. In that directive, there is a $watch function that constantly updates the time string. However, it sounds like your requirement is to show a snapshot of the time at which the page loaded (that is, when the program runs). If you don't want to continuously update the time, you can simplify the directive - instead of the $watch and timeout related functions, just set `format=new Date()`. If this does not solve the problem, then please clarify the requirement you are trying to solve.